# Running batch files on a schedule

Tags: batch-file

I have a machine that I connect to it remotely by Remote Desktop connection and I map it's IP and can connect to it's hard drives.
Every morning I run 3 batch files that pull text data from the machine.
Is there a way through Batch commands to automatically run those 3 files as a schedule task every morning at 7:00AM from example? 
I searched answers for this issue and most of them answered to do that through Windows schedule task, but it is not working for me due to the Remote connection. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried configuring the scheduled task on the remote machine?

Comment: I don't understand why you need a remote desktop connection if you are pulling the data from the remote computer. The way I understand it, you would run the batch file from your computer so you would create a scheduled task on your computer.